# Image in Table not aligned properly

Tags: itext

I'm using iText library for my android project for creating PDF files. I have created the PDF successfully using the library. But I'm facing an issue in alignment for table. I have a image in the first column, that image is getting shrink and cutoff only for the first row. Rest of the rows its working fine as expected. Please find the attached screenshot and the source code below

```
for(int i = 0; i < deductiblesArray.length(); i++) {

            Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromAssets("images/count_bg.png", mContext);
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
            Image imgBusinessLogo = null;
            int indentation = 0;
            try {
                imgBusinessLogo = Image.getInstance("images/count_bg.png");
                imgBusinessLogo.scaleToFit(50f, 50f);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            imgBusinessLogo.setAlignment(Image.MIDDLE);
            PdfPCell c1 = new PdfPCell(imgBusinessLogo, false);
            c1.setCellEvent(new WatermarkedCell("" + arrDeductiblesCountArray.getString(i)));
            //c1.setImage(imgBusinessLogo);
            c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
            c1.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
            c1.setRowspan(3);
            c1.setPaddingBottom(5);
            c1.setPaddingTop(5);
            //c1.setFixedHeight(100);
            c1.setBorder(0);
            table.addCell(c1);

            c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Name"));
            c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
            c1.setBorder(0);
            c1.setPaddingBottom(5);
            c1.setPaddingTop(5);
            c1.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY);
            table.addCell(c1);
```

[Image is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VebDp.png)

Comment: We'd need a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) before we can look into this.

Comment: Click on the link [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) and you'll find out. It's a well-known concept on [SO](http://stackoverflow.com).